# Cypress with the ContextMenu not work - React Contextify

Tags: reactjs, cypress

i'm using a library called React Contexty, and it has a *menu* that is inside of the Contextify and is called of ContextMenu, when i do request for it to click in the Item of the ContextMenu, it click but the action not happens.

Cypress:

```js
cy.get("img[data-test=img--menu-candidate]")
  .click({
    force: true
  })

cy.get(".testinhoImg").click({
  force: true
})
```

My MenuContext:

```js
        <ContextMenu id={`menu-${this.props.candidate.id}`} animation={animation.fade} theme={theme.light}>
          <Item>
            <div style={{ width: '50px', marginLeft: '0.5em', marginRight: '0.5em' }}>
              <img src={ViewSrc} alt="View" />
            </div>
            <span className="ibm-plex-sans-serif-regular ibm-textcolor-blue-60"> View </span>
          </Item>
```

Somebody know why? And help-me please?

HTML:

```html
<div class="react-contexify react-contexify__theme--light react-contexify__will-enter--fade" style="left: 447px; top: 308px; opacity: 1;">
  <div>
    <div class="react-contexify__item" role="presentation">
      <div class="react-contexify__item__data">
        <div style="width: 50px; margin-left: 0.5em; margin-right: 0.5em;"><img src="/static/media/view.2844f64a.svg" alt="View"></div><span class="ibm-plex-sans-serif-regular ibm-textcolor-blue-60"> View </span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="react-contexify__separator"></div>
    <div class="react-contexify__item" role="presentation">
      <div class="react-contexify__item__data">
        <div style="width: 65px;"><img src="/static/media/move.f7f8dc44.svg" alt="Move to folder" style="margin-left: 0.5em; margin-right: 0.5em;"></div><span class="ibm-plex-sans-serif-regular ibm-textcolor-blue-60">Move to folder</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="react-contexify__item" role="presentation">
      <div class="react-contexify__item__data">
        <div style="width: 50px; padding-right: 1em;"><img src="/static/media/email.330dcb30.svg" alt="Send Email" style="padding-right: 1em;"></div><span class="ibm-plex-sans-serif-regular ibm-textcolor-blue-60">Send Email</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="react-contexify__item react-contexify__item--disabled" role="presentation">
      <div class="react-contexify__item__data">
        <div style="width: 65px;"><img src="/static/media/remove-folder.d620c9fb.svg" alt="Move to folder" style="margin-left: 0.5em; margin-right: 0.5em;"></div><span class="ibm-plex-sans-serif-regular ibm-textcolor-blue-60">Remove from folder</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="react-contexify__item" role="presentation">
      <div class="react-contexify__item__data">
        <div style="width: 50px; margin-left: 0.5em; margin-right: 0.5em;"><img src="/static/media/delete.e899d653.svg" alt="Delete" style="padding-right: 1.2em;"></div><span class="ibm-plex-sans-serif-regular ibm-textcolor-blue-60">Delete</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with React, but it doesn't look like either of your selectors match any of the elements you have in your code; I'm assuming this is because React inserts its own data into the DOM. Could you post the HTML as it appears when loaded into the browser?

Comment: @JoshuaWade Hi Joshua, allright, 1 second..

Comment: @JoshuaWade See if is this that you want?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. I still don't see either of those selectors in the code you posted. What are they selecting? Are they dynamically inserted by your Cypress code?

Comment: Yes, are dynamically, 
it click but the action (that is a console.log) not work.

Comment: This is still not something I can reproduce or step through in my head since I don't have all the components. You haven't posted any code that inserts a `data-test` attribute, so as far as I can see from what you've posted so far, your code will break. Please consider posting a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as I do not yet have enough information to help.

Comment: I think you can get somewhere by trying a different selector, like `cy.get('img[src="/static/media/view.2844f64a.svg"]').click()`.